# How to accurate scale start velocity in projectile motions?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

I have projectile motion where the angle $\alpha$ is $45^\circ$, and the start velocity is $45\ \rm{m/s}$. We can then expect it to land about $206.422\ \rm m$ away; however, if I were to change/stretch out my scale so that $1\ \rm m$ would be equal to $10\ \rm m$, what would I have to devide/multiply my start velocity by to get the same result?

I must note this is for a realistic learning game/app, not a homework task.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "same result"

Comment: by same result i mean that if i were to fire the object x distance on screen, and then in game i would say now that distance is 10 times longer, what velocity does it need to be for it to land on the same spot... did that help?

Comment: Do you want the same physical spot, or if you define a new unit "$\eta$" such that $1\ \rm m=10\ \eta$, you want the new projectile to travel $x \ \eta$ if the old one traveled $x\ \rm m$?

Comment: Also, I'm removing my answer until the question is clarified.

Comment: As i understand it, i think i want the same physical spot.

Comment: Then you just need to do a simple unit conversion. If you get suck just think about going between meters and kilometers.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.